# Do orthodox christians eat pork and are they circumcised?

Tags: eastern-orthodox, diet, circumcision

Peace be with you.
I want to know if Orthodox Christians eat pork, and are they circumcised?
I am referring to the early church which is the Orthodox Christians because in the Bible it says Yeshua (messiah) never ate pork and he was circumcised.  Pork is haram as I understand.

Do the Orthodox Christians follow this even today: circumcision and not eating pork?

Comment: If by "Orthodox Christians" you mean the official Orthodox Church today, then refer to my answer.  If you mean something else, you should probably clarify.

Comment: *Yeshua (messiah) never ate pork and he was circumcised* - Correct. And He was also Jewish; but He did not require anyone to be Jewish themselves, or keep Jewish customs, to show grace unto them; this is seen in passages such as Matthew 8:5-13, Luke 4:24-27, 7:2-10.

Answer (score 2):

Orthodox Christians can be circumcised for medical or hygienic purposes, but it is not mandatory.

[Circumcision - Questions & Answers](https://oca.org/questions/teaching/circumcision)

They definitely are allowed to eat pork, and most do. There are fasts you are supposed to observe throughout the year, where you are supposed to abstain from all meat, including pork.

There are some African Orthodox branches (Coptic, Ethiopian, etc) where circumcision is mandated and pork is not allowed. But these churches are not in communion within the Eastern Orthodox Church as they split over Christological issues during the first few centuries of the church.

Comment: The prohibition of pork for Coptics has been questioned. If you can shed any light on which groups that and mandatory circumcision apply to it would be helpful, preferably with references and/or quotes.